# Integration gives very different answers when some variables are specified

Tags: symbolic

When Matematica does this integral

$\int \frac{k}{\sqrt{a^2 n^2 y^2+2 a n^2 y-k^2+n^2}} \, dy$

the result is
$k \left(\frac{\log \left(\frac{a n y+n}{\sqrt{(a n y+n)^2-k^2}}+1\right)}{2 a n}-\frac{\log \left(1-\frac{a n y+n}{\sqrt{(a n y+n)^2-k^2}}\right)}{2 a n}\right)$

When I substitute in 1 for n and .01 for a, the result is complex for k between -1 and + 1 (approx, is 0 at k=0)

When I put periods after some numbers I get a different result.

$\int \frac{k}{\sqrt{\text{gocsq}^{2.} n^2 y^2+2 \text{gocsq} n^2 y-1. k^2+1. n^2}} \, dy$

the result is
$\frac{1. k \sqrt{n^2 (2. a y+1.)-1. k^2}}{a n^2}$

I pasted the wrong result initially. The initial answer is complex while the second answer is real for n=1,a=.01 and k^2<1, such as .98.

Do you see if I did something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: could you post the mathematica code you used in plain text format?

Comment: \[Integral]k/(\[Sqrt](-k^2+n^2+2gocsq n^2 y+gocsq^2 n^2 y^2))\[DifferentialD]y   =k (-(Log[1-(n+gocsq n y)/Sqrt[-k^2+(n+gocsq n y)^2]]/(2 gocsq n))+Log[1+(n+gocsq n y)/Sqrt[-k^2+(n+gocsq n y)^2]]/(2 gocsq n))      continued

Comment: \[Integral]k/(Sqrt[-1.` k^2+1.` n^2+2 gocsq n^2 y+gocsq^2` n^2 y^2])\[DifferentialD]y    (1. k Sqrt[-1. k^2+n^2 (1. +2. gocsq y)])/(gocsq n^2)

Answer (score 3):

The integrals are actually anti-derivatives and each has an implied arbitrary constant which can be complex and differ from each other. There is no reason to assume that the two should be equal.

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = k/Sqrt[a^2 n^2 y^2 + 2 a n^2 y - k^2 + n^2];

int = Assuming[Element[{a, k, n, y}, Reals],
  Integrate[expr, y] // FullSimplify]

(* (1/(2 a n))(2 k ArcTanh[(Sqrt[-k^2 + (n + a n y)^2] - y Abs[a] Abs[n])/n] - 
  k (Log[-n + Sqrt[-k^2 + (n + a n y)^2] - y Abs[a n]] + 
     Log[n + Sqrt[-k^2 + (n + a n y)^2] - y Abs[a n]]) Sign[a] Sign[n]) *)
```

Verifying that `int` is a valid anti-derivative.

```
Assuming[Element[{a, k, n, y}, Reals],
 expr == D[int, y] // FullSimplify]

(* True *)
```

For particular values of `n` and `a`

```
int2 = Assuming[Element[{k, y}, Reals],
  Integrate[expr /. {n -> 1, a -> 1/100}, y] // Simplify]

(* -100 k Log[-100 - y + Sqrt[-10000 k^2 + (100 + y)^2]] *)
```

Verifying that `int2` is a valid anti-derivative .

```
Assuming[Element[{k, y}, Reals],
 (expr /. {n -> 1, a -> 1/100}) == D[int2, y] // Simplify]

(* True *)

int3 = int /. {n -> 1, a -> 1/100} // 
  FullSimplify[#, Element[{k, y}, Reals]] &

(* -50 k (Log[-1 + Sqrt[-k^2 + (1 + y/100)^2] - y/100] + 
   Log[1 - Sqrt[-k^2 + (1 + y/100)^2] + y/100]) *)
```

Verifying that `int3` is a valid anti-derivative .

```
Assuming[Element[{k, y}, Reals],
 (expr /. {n -> 1, a -> 1/100}) == D[int3, y] // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not see that you verified my alternative result of the integration,

Answer (score 2):

This shows both agree. This plots the real part and the imaginary parts of the result of integration, done both ways. First is by substitution into the integrand *before* and the second by substitution *after*

Then the result is plotted for `y` from `-2..2`. It shows both give same result. Shift is OK, since two integrands that different by a constant additive shift are both correct because the constant differentiates back to zero, so it has no effect on the anti-derivative.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
integrand = k/Sqrt[a^2*n^2*y^2 + 2*a*n^2*y - k^2 + n^2];
param = {n -> 1, a -> 1/100};
anti = Integrate[integrand, y];
dataRe = Table[
   anti2 = Integrate[integrand /. param /. k -> m, y]; 
   anti1 = anti /. param /. k -> m;
   Grid[{{Row[{"k=", m}]},
     {Plot[{Re@anti1, Re@anti2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]}
     }, Frame -> All]
   ,
   {m, -1, 1, 1/4}
   ];

 dataRe
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And for imaginary part

```
dataIm = Table[
   anti2 = Integrate[integrand /. param /. k -> m, y]; 
   anti1 = anti /. param /. k -> m;
   Grid[{{Row[{"k=", m}]},
     {Plot[{Im@anti1, Im@anti2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]}
     }, Frame -> All]
   ,
   {m, -1, 1, 1/4}
   ];

 dataIm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. I see I messed up in posting my question accurately. I will try again. I apologize for wasting your time.